# Google Maps Android SDK + ViewModel / retainInstance

Tags: android, fragment, viewmodel, retain

In my app I have a fragment holding a Google Maps view. I'm using setRetainInstance to keep my fragment when the user rotates his device, to avoid reloading data on the map (the app can load KML files, which can take a few seconds to load. Reloading them upon rotation wouldn't be user friendly at all).

Now that setRetainInstance has been deprecated in favor of ViewModel, how can I keep the same behavior (without using configChanges in the manifest)?

Comment: Views hold a hard reference to the Activity that created it. That means holding onto one over configuration changes is a memory leak. It sounds like you're already leaking memory.

Comment: Well in production I'm currently using configChanges, and I'm trying to improve that. Do you see another option? Using SupportMapFragment instead of MapView and retaining that fragment would be the same, right?

Comment: You can't retain that fragment either, no. If you're already handling config changes, then you don't need retained fragments or ViewModels.

Comment: Well the goal was to stop handling config changes, as it causes some bugs (or unhandled cases) when for instance starting another activity, rotating the screen and coming back. I wonder if I can just keep the GoogleMap object passed in the onMapReady callback, but that likely has a reference to the view as well, otherwise I can't see how could it update the map.